# Unable to save csv files using ImageJ macro

Tags: csv, macros, imagej

I'm using ImageJ to try to export the raw data values of the grayscale mean of a rectangular region of interest over time. I don't have much experience with macros, but here's what I have so far.

```
 makeRectangle(75, 45, 44, 43); // ROI selected
 run("Plot Z-axis Profile", "profile=time"); // graph relating mean and time is generated
 saveAs("Results", "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/PlotValues.csv"); // csv file is generated
```

Running this macro produces the graph, but the csv file in't created.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `Plot.showValues()` just before the `saveAs` line fixed the problem.